# WebWorkers - new Worker keeps requesting same script from server

Tags: javascript, html, http, web-worker, web-frontend

On my server I have this logged:

```
GET /js/workers/one.js 200 2.509 ms - 828
GET /js/workers/one.js 304 1.593 ms - -
GET /js/workers/one.js 304 0.499 ms - -
GET /js/workers/one.js 304 0.464 ms - -
GET /js/workers/one.js 304 1.101 ms - -
```

(notice the 200, followed by 4 304s)

in my front-end code, there is this:

```
  var myWorker = new Worker('/js/workers/one.js');
```

why doesn't my front-end cache this file somehow? It keeps requesting the same file every time I call `new Worker()` ...

one way to solve it (maybe) might be to put the file in a `<script>` tag like so:

```
<script src="/js/workers/one.js"></script>
```

the problem with this, however, is that "importScripts" will not work

perhaps this will work?

```
if(typeof importScripts === 'function'){
    importScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.js');
    importScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.js');
}
```

what is the best way to prevent new Worker() from re-requesting a file?

UPDATE:

If I put the js/workers.one.js file in a script tag like so

```
<script src="/js/workers/one"></script>
```

then the server does this:

```
GET /js/workers/one.js 304 0.521 ms - -
GET /js/workers/one.js 304 0.605 ms - -
GET /js/workers/one.js 304 0.289 ms - -
GET /js/workers/one.js 304 0.300 ms - -
GET /js/workers/one.js 304 0.347 ms - -
```

(notice the 5 304s)

so it's already loaded, (unlike before where there was one 200 response), but new Worker() keeps requesting it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[304 status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1) means that your browser does have the file cached actually and is explicitly allowed to reuse it by the server. The request is performed because the cached version is considered [stale](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2) for some reason and must be [validated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.3) by the server.

When serving the file you can explicitly indicate its freshness lifetime by adding some http headers in the response with the file data. You can add [`Expires` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) with the date/time after which the
response is considered stale, e.g.:

```
Expires: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 16:00:00 GMT
```

With `Cache-control` header and [`max-age` response directive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.8) you can indicate that the response is to be considered stale after its age is greater than the specified number of seconds:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=600
```